# Google OCR - just in Lens, or can I find it elsewhere?

Tags: google-chrome, android, google-drive, ocr, google-docs

I need to convert some screenshots of spreadsheets to actual data.  Google Lens seems pretty good at this - I save the image on my phone, then open it up with the Google Lens app, let it do it's thing, then copy and paste the results into an email that I send to myself, then open the email on my laptop.

Seems a bit convoluted though.  As far as I can see there's no online version of Google Lens that I could access from my laptop and upload the jpeg to?

I thought if I put the image into google docs or google drive I might find OCR in there somewhere, but I don't seem able to?